# How to override event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class that inherits from `ContextMenuStrip`. I use the `OnOpening` event to enable/disable menu items as required:

```
protected override void OnOpening(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnOpening(e);

    var count = bindingSource.Count;
    var item = (T)bindingSource.Current;

    removeMenuItem.Enabled = item != null;
    removeAllMenuItem.Enabled = count > 0;
}
```

The above works fine for standard requirements. However, now I have a situation where I want to override the above method within the parent form.

So I tried to do the following:

```
myContextStrip.Opening += (s, ea) =>
{
    var current = bindingSource.Current as MyItem;

    myContextStrip.RemoveMenuItem.Enabled = !current?.IsDeleted ?? true;
    myContextStrip.RemoveAllMenuItem.Enabled = bindingSource.Count > 0;
};
```

Implementing the above doesn't work as expected because the class 'OnOpening' method is still being called after the above is called.

Is there a better way to override the `OnOpening` event within the parent form and stop it from further calling the code in the derived contextmenu class?

Comment: `OnOpening` isn't an event - it's a method. The event is just `Opening`, and you're not overriding it, you're subscribing to it. If you *actually* want to override the `OnOpening` method, you'll need a derived class.

Comment: The `OnOpening` method (not event) is not invoked after your event, your code is firing the event before it does anything,  Move  `base.OnOpening(e);` to the end of the method.  That way code in the event handler wont be undone

Comment: @JonSkeet If there's an alternative I would like to avoid using a new derived class.

Comment: There isn't. If anything calls your `OnOpening` method, it *will* execute the method in the first snippet you've shown, unless you've overridden it. The event handlers are only being called as part of the execution of that method.

Comment: Your form class is consumer of the event. The consumer can only consume `Opening` event which is raised by `OnOpening` method of your control. If you want to override the default behavior of the `OnOpening` in event handler and decide to execute or prevent executing default logic of `OnOpening`, there are some patterns which you can follow. In all patterns you need to override  `OnOpening` in a way which allows you to control executing/prevent execution of default code from the event handler.